# Prove that: $\left( \sum_{k=1}^{6}a_kb_k\right)^2 \leq \sum_{k=1}^{6}a_kb_k^2$

Tags: inequality

Q: Let $a_1, a_2, a_3,a_4, a_5, a_6$ be positive real number whose sum is 1 and $b_1,b_2,b_3,b_4,b_5,b_6$ real number. 
Prove that:

$$\left( \sum_{k=1}^{6}a_kb_k\right)^2 \leq \sum_{k=1}^{6}a_kb_k^2$$.

What should I do here? I don't even know where to start from. Please help me by giving me a hint.

Comment: Why 6 and not a general $n$ ? This is a little misleading...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write $$\sum_{k=1}^6 a_kb_k = \sum_{k=1}^6 \sqrt{a_k} \left( \sqrt{a_k} b_k \right)$$
and apply the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Comment: Fantastic!! elegant..

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative solution to Umberto P's answer, you can use the fact that the square function $f(x)=x^2$ is convex.

Comment: Maybe add the words "Jensen's inequality" for those who don't know them...